# how to select :after element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Bellow is my codes.what i have tried.when this popup appear i want to use this close button to close entire popbox.

CSS code

```
.bigdiv{
    display:none;
    background-color:#efefef;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 100000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border:2px solid #efefef;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:500;
    top:25%;
    left:25%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    }
    .bigdiv:after {
        cursor:pointer;
        content:url('http://static.doers.lk/img/closebox.png');
        position: relative;
        right: -195px;
        top: -310px;
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

JQUERY

```
$(".left div").click(function () {

   $(".bigdiv").show("slow");


    $(".bigdiv").click(function () {
   $(".bigdiv").hide();
   }) ;  }) ;
```

HTML

```
<div class="left">
<div>intro text here</div><div></div><div></div>
</div>


<div class="bigdiv">some content</div>
```

I want to select :after elements .how to do that using jquery ?

Comment: jQuery (and of course javascript in general) does not support the CSS pseudo classes `:after` and `:before`.

Comment: or is there any way to select that closebox image using jquery ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to select :after elements .how to do that using jquery ?

You can't, generated pseudo-elements don't exist in the DOM (yet, sadly).

We can prove this like so:

CSS:

```
#foo:before {
  content: '[Before]'
}
#foo:after {
  content: '[After]'
}
```

HTML:

```
<body><div id="foo">Foo</div></body>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {

  var msgs = [];
  var child;
  var div;

  for (child = document.body.firstChild;
       child;
       child = child.nextSibling) {
    if (child.id) {
      msgs.push("Child " + child.nodeName + "#" + child.id);
    }
    else {
      msgs.push("Child " + child.nodeName);
    }
  }

  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = msgs.join("<br>");
  document.body.appendChild(div);

})();
```

The page resulting from the above (if we assume the `script` element is added to `body` at the end) is:

```
[Before]Foo[After]
Child DIV#foo
Child SCRIPT
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/etirax/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/etirax/1/edit)

As you can see, the generated pseudo-elements are just not present at all as far as the DOM is concerned.

Comment: or is there any way to select that closebox image using jquery ?

Comment: @xman: If by "select" you mean get a reference to it so you can do things to it, no, the element just doesn't exist at the JavaScript level at all. If you want to affect the image, you have to dynamically generate CSS for the `.bigdiv:after` selector (or, of course, a more specific one) and add it to the page.

Comment: ok thanks.:) i'm going to create that without using after .thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the getComputedStyle function, which is supported by most major browsers - IE9,IE10,Chrome,FF. I have not found a way to do this in IE8 though.

```
var attrContent = getComputedStyle(this,':after').content;
var attrWidth = getComputedStyle(this,':after').width;
```

If you find this function is undefined try window.getComputedStyle instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't select pseudo-elements in jQuery (or JavaScript in general).

jQuery's `appendTo()` method works exactly like CSS `:after` though, so it might work as a replacement (albeit not so elegant as pure CSS solution).

e.g instead of:

```
.bigdiv:after {
    cursor:pointer;
    content:url('http://static.doers.lk/img/closebox.png');
    position: relative;
    right: -195px;
    top: -310px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Try it like this

CSS:

```
.bigdivAfter {
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    right: -195px;
    top: -310px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

JS:

```
$("<div class=bigdivAfter><img src='http://static.doers.lk/img/closebox.png'></div>").appendTo(".bigdiv");
```

And then you can select the closebox image as normal.

Comment: or is there any way to select that closebox image using jquery ?

Comment: there is a problem i open the popup box 2,3 times that image append to to the pop box vertically .how i stop that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to append close button and can assign an close event to it.
This jquery and css will work for you.

**CSS**

```
.bigdivAfter {
    cursor:pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: //as you want;
    top: //as you want;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".bigdiv").append('<img class="closeButton" src="http://static.doers.lk/img/closebox.png"/>');
$(".bigdiv .closeButton").click(function () {
   $(".bigdiv").hide();
   }) ;
$(".left div").click(function () {
   $(".bigdiv").show("slow");
}) ;
```

I will also suggest you to add image on html itself instead of adding it trough jquery