# how can i get rid of the semicolon using jquery

Tags: html, css

here's what i have. i want to get rid of : that has no label name and cant figure out in jquery. tnx. . . .

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <label for="salutation">Salutation</label>
    <select>
      <option></option>
    </select> 
    </li>
    <li><label></label>
    <input type="text"/>
    </li>
</ul>   


 label {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: right;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 25px;

 }
 ul li > label:after, ul li > label:after 
 {
 content: ":";
 }
```

[Here's in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3U8T/372/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You only want to display the colon (not semicolon) if the label has text?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this can't be done with jQuery. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001350/how-to-select-after-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the labels and check for text:

**JS**

```
$("label").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text()) {
        $(this).addClass("colon-after");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.colon-after:after {
    content:":";
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/L3U8T/374/)

Answer (score 0):

I Have Updated you css and here is the jsfiddle

```
( http://jsfiddle.net/8ck8v/ )
```