# Trigger select dropdown on pseudoelement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to trigger dropdown list (select options) when clicking :after (arrow)? Maybe my code could be better for this design but it is the only solution I finally came up with that works ok.

[image]

HTML

```
<label>
    <select>
        <option selected>jkjhhkl</option>
        <option>asdfasd</option>
        <option>dfgdfgfd</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

CSS

```
select {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #f6f6f6;
    font: 400 13px "Open Sans",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

label {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
}

label:after {
    content: '\f107';
    font: 22px "FontAwesome";
    color: #f6f6f6;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sworj0ta/1/

Comment: Don't use a pseudo-element, instead use a label with the for attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992639/can-i-open-a-selectbox-with-javascript

Comment: [_"generated pseudo-elements are just not present at all as far as the DOM is concerned"_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001381/1746830)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/2232xzy8/1/

I positioned the select box above the `label` and `label:before` and moved the background color only to `label` element while keeping `select`'s background transparent.

Therefore it looks like you're clicking the arrow but in fact you click the select box.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I will only add border-left: 4px solid #fff; to :before since that spacing is intented

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="styled-select">
<select>
  <option>Here is the first option</option>
  <option>The second option</option>
</select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.styled-select select {
background: transparent;
width: 268px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1;
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
height: 34px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}


.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(http://bavotasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/down_arrow_select.jpg) no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
```